# OData v4.0 How to set MaxExpansionDepth?

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, odata, expansion

---

Hi Everyone,

- I need a setting in Get() method **[EnableQuery(MaxExpansionDepth=3)]** to limit expansion depth in OData query.
- I tried to set this attribute in Get() method but it does not work.

***Could you please give me a suggestion for this?***

Follow as : https://github.com/OData/odata.net

Many Thanks

Comment: Hi, please show us the actual code you have tried and the exact error message. "Does not work" is not sufficient for us to understand the problem.

Comment: I want to have an error message when I expand level more than Max Expansion Depth.
E.g.
"var queryOptions = new ODataQueryOptions(queryContext, Request)"
--> queryOptions.SelectExpand.SelectExpandClause should show an exception "Not allowed - the level expansion is more than Max expansion depth"
I don't know where to set Max Expansion Depth.
Please give me your advice, Stefan.
Thanks

Comment: Which library you are using? And which version you are using?
If you are using Web Api OData 6.0,  you can refer to http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#13-01-modelbound-attribute, and see Expand attribute.

Comment: I'm using Web Api OData 6.0, currently, I use below method to handle the validations:
"enableQueryAttribute.ValidateQuery(Request, queryOptions)"
Thanks all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
[EnableQuery(MaxExpansionDepth = 4)]
public IQueryable<abc> Get() 
{
    return GetAQueryable<abc>();
}
```

before your method name add it.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I needed to set the maximum expansion depth in the entity when creating the edm model.

In the startup, you configure your route and your model:

```
routes.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", ODataDataSourceProvider.GetEdmModel(new ODataConventionModelBuilder()));
```

In your provider:

```
public IEdmModel GetEdmModel(ODataModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.EntitySet<Object>("Objects");

        builder
            .EntityType<Object>()
            .Filter() // Enables filtering
            .Expand(3) // Enables expanding with maximum depth: 3
            .Select(); // Enables selecting

        return builder.Build();
    }
```

Then, in your controller you can override the maximum depth value, as long as it is less than the maximum defined in the entity configuration:

```
[HttpGet]
[EnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All, MaxExpansionDepth = 2)]
public SingleResult<Object> Get(Guid key){ }
```

Comment: `.Expand(3)` does not have any effect!